# Encoding UUID to Base62 (not Base64) in Java

Tags: java, encoding, uuid, base62

I'm trying to shorten UUID values (stored in DB as UUID, not string) to be embedded in URLs. I'm aware of Base64 for URL, but trying to see if I can make it without dash and underscore characters.
So I would like to convert UUID to base62. After a lot of googling I found:

1. There's not a standard for this (something like RFC2045), am I right?
2. Most importantly there's no proper implementation for it. I found a lot of snippets on how to do it, but with some sort of note that "this is a naive implementation" or something. Is there a proper implementation (I don't mind the exact interpretation how the mapping should be done as long as it's done properly)?
3. There are some base classes in Apache Commons Codec and Guava which are extended for Base32 and Base64, but I didn't find it easy to extend it for Base62. Is it even possible to do it (considering the fact that the mapping is fundamentally different)?
   Thanks.

Comment: mime base64 does not use dash or underscore

Comment: @IłyaBursov MIME Base64 makes it even worth since it needs URL encoding.

Comment: @RusselYang dash and underscore don't need escaping, am I missing something?

Comment: @Rad. you are right. then why not just base64, you can include raw UUID string too.

Comment: @Rad not really, both `+` and `/` are allowed in URLs, so you might need correct decoding, to avoid conversion

Comment: You're probably better off using the standard Base64Url encoding -- this is exactly what it was designed for.

Comment: @IłyaBursov I'm not following, `/` must be encoded in the URL, right? that's why we have `Base64Url`. I don't like to have anything other than alphanumeric, let alone slash (`foo/bar` -> `foo%2Fbar`)

Comment: @Rad no, look at your browser - it has unescaped slashes `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52414740/encoding-uuid-to-base62-in-java`

Comment: @IłyaBursov, yes but then how can I extract the `{user-id}` segment from `/users/foo/bar` (URL template: `/users/{user-id}`)? (Even if it's possible seems really weird to me, no?)

Comment: @Rad something like `rawUrl.substring(rawUrl.indexOf("/user/"))` will give you string back

Comment: quote: Using standard Base64 in URL requires encoding of `+`, `/` and `=` characters into special percent-encoded hexadecimal sequences, which makes the string unnecessarily longer.

Comment: Yes, but if I were your developer and came to you with that code in my spring application what would be your reaction? :D

Comment: @Rad it is true _only_ if you're using `/` as special delimiter (which a lot of systems do), but you can parse raw url by yourself

Comment: Yes, got your point.

Comment: @Rad my reaction would be `oh, they're trying to optimize size of the url and they avoid unneeded parsing, which is faster, cool` :)

Comment: @IłyaBursov then I'd love to work in your team :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might want to try this library: https://github.com/Devskiller/friendly-id

> The FriendlyID library converts a given UUID (with 36 characters) to a URL-friendly ID (a "FriendlyID") which is based on Base62 (with a maximum of 22 characters), as in the example below:
>
> ```
>    UUID                                        Friendly ID
>    
>    c3587ec5-0976-497f-8374-61e0c2ea3da5   ->   5wbwf6yUxVBcr48AMbz9cb
>    |                                           |                              
>    36 characters                               22 characters or less
> ```
>
> In addition, this library allows to:
>
> - convert from a FriendlyID back to the original UUID; and
> - create a new, random FriendlyID

Comment: I'm pretty sure I had found this lib at the time, but can't recall why I didn't use it.

Comment: Quick warning about FriendlyID vs. other Base62 libs: FriendlyID uses inversed letter case compared to standard Base62. Its alphabet is 0123456789ABC...abc... and not the standard 0123456789abc...ABC...

Answer (score 2):

You can encode UUIDs efficiently to base-62 using [`Base62Codec`](https://github.com/f4b6a3/uuid-creator/wiki/4.0.-Library-codecs#base62codec).

```java
String string = Base62Codec.INSTANCE.encode(uuid);
```

You can also generate Friendly IDs with 22 characters or less.

```java
public static String getFriendlyID() {
    return Base62Codec.INSTANCE.encode(UUID.randomUUID());
}

public static String getFriendlyID(int length) {
    return Base62Codec.INSTANCE.encode(UUID.randomUUID())
                      .substring(0, Math.min(length, 22));
}
```

`Base62Codec` is a codec of [uuid-creator](https://github.com/f4b6a3/uuid-creator).

**NOTE:** the alphabet used by `Base62Codec` is "0-9A-Za-z", which is compatible with "C" collation (LC_COLLATE=C), which in turn makes `libc` sort strings in ASCII order, i.e., "AAA" is sorted before "aaa".

---

**Disclaimer**: I'm the main contributor of `uuid-creator`.